# Android got ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException in onResume()?

Tags: android

I see an exception from my google play console :

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException:
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:5365)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:5431)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence (TransactionExecutor.java:225)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath (TransactionExecutor.java:201)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState (TransactionExecutor.java:173)
  at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:97)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2571)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
  at android.os.Looper.loopOnce (Looper.java:226)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:313)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8741)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:571)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1067)
Caused by android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException:
  at android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException$1.createFromParcel (ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException.java:54)
  at android.app.ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException$1.createFromParcel (ForegroundServiceStartNotAllowedException.java:50)
  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelableInternal (Parcel.java:4784)
  at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable (Parcel.java:4752)
  at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull (Parcel.java:3018)
  at android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:3007)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2990)
  at android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2932)
  at android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.startService (IActivityManager.java:6201)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startServiceCommon (ContextImpl.java:1967)
  at android.app.ContextImpl.startForegroundService (ContextImpl.java:1933)
  at android.content.ContextWrapper.startForegroundService (ContextWrapper.java:839)
  at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat$Api26Impl.startForegroundService (ContextCompat.java:931)
  at androidx.core.content.ContextCompat.startForegroundService (ContextCompat.java:703)
  at myPackage.myApplication.myFragment.onResume (myFragment.java:445)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performResume (Fragment.java:3039)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.resume (FragmentStateManager.java:607)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStateManager.java:306)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStore.java:112)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1647)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange (FragmentManager.java:3128)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchResume (FragmentManager.java:3086)
  at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performResume (Fragment.java:3048)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.resume (FragmentStateManager.java:607)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStateManager.java:306)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState (FragmentStore.java:112)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1647)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange (FragmentManager.java:3128)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchResume (FragmentManager.java:3086)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume (FragmentController.java:273)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments (FragmentActivity.java:458)
  at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume (FragmentActivity.java:447)
  at android.app.Activity.performResume (Activity.java:8746)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity (ActivityThread.java:5338)
```

I amend the error message that showing my app name to:

```
    at myPackage.myApplication.myFragment.onResume (myFragment.java:445)
```

As this error is from an android 13 samsung device, so I created an android 13 device in emulator, but cannot simulate the error...
I read the developer document about this excption, it is to prevent starting foreground service from background, I dont understand how starting a service in onResume() is deemed as from background?

Below is the onResume() method in myFragment.java

`sc` is ServiceConnection.class

This error is from the 2nd last line `ContextCompat.startForegroundService()`

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    iFilter = new IntentFilter( "" + someId ) ;
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getContext()).registerReceiver(
                localBroadcastReceiver,
                iFilter);

    Intent bindIntent = new Intent(getActivity(), myService.class);
    ContextCompat.startForegroundService( getActivity(), bindIntent );
    getActivity().bindService(bindIntent, sc, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
}
```

I suspect that this is a bug?

Comment: I only just found this question, but I'm also trying to replicate in the emulator and failing. I posted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77230944/cant-replicate-foregroundservicestartnotallowedexception-within-emulator in which I mentioned you can ask the ActivityManager to log a message when such a restricted action is made. Maybe we just have to watch for this, instead of the exception.